# UITableView detail button not responding

Tags: swift

My 'accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith' is not working, and I'm stumped why.
It displays fine in the table, but nothing happens when I click on it.  I've also tried using 'detailDisplayButton' feature.

[image]

Here is the storyboard and code...can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? The delete row function is working fine. It's just never getting to the part where it's supposed to parse the text and send the date information to a new controller. (BTW, those are not our real birthdates.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the other `UITableViewDelegate` method called, ie, is the `delegate` set?

Comment: Yes:  class InitViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

Comment: Your class is compliant with the protocol, but it doesn't mean that the `yourTableView.delegate` isn't nil.

Comment: OK, please excuse my noviceness (is that a word?).  How exactly would I do that?  Everything else pertaining to my table works fine.